# C# Update ProgressBar from Thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, progress-bar

I have Windows form in XAML that contains progress bars.  Threads are spawned, the jobs run, and the status of the jobs are shown with progress bars.

It's working OK, but I want to also limit the number of jobs that can be run at one time.

```
    protected int executingThreads = 0;
    int maxThreadCount = 3;
    object lockObj = new object();

    public virtual void start()
    {
        inqueue = new Queue<XElement>();

        LoadQueue();

        while (inqueue.Count != 0)
        {
            XElement request = inputqueue.Dequeue();

            System.Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new System.Threading.WaitCallback(DoWork), request);

 /*         lock (lockObj)
            {
                executingThreads++;
                while (executingThreads == maxThreadCount)
                    Thread.Sleep(1);
            }  */
        }
 /*         while (executingThreads != 0)
            Thread.Sleep(1);  */

    }
```

To limit the number of jobs running at one time, I added the code that's shown here commented out with the lock and the sleep.  This seems to limit the number of jobs running at one time and all jobs complete successfully.

But the ProgressBar no longer is incrementally displaying updates -- until all jobs finish and then everything is shown as completed.  I assume that the sleep prevents the ProgressBar UI to refresh.  How can I fix that?
Is the solution Application.DoEvents() ?

Comment: A thread pool already uses a limited number of threads, you should just be able to tell it the correct number to use instead of artificially limiting it.

Comment: ThreadPool.SetMaxThread() does the limitation of threads that can queued to ThreadPool.

Comment: Does setting something like ThreadPool.SetMaxThread(3,3) affect only my code?  Should it be set back once all jobs are done?

Comment: The ThreadPool is application specific, so you will not affect anything else. [From MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Threading.ThreadPool(v=vs.110).aspx) `The thread pool enables you to use threads more efficiently by providing your application with a pool of worker threads that are managed by the system`

Comment: The solution is NEVER `Application.DoEvents()`. That is a bad bad bad way to go.